# Keying a generic type using a Symbol in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, metaprogramming, symbols

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
function attachUUID<T>(o:T) {
   o[Symbol('id')]=v1();
}
```

The `T` generic type is a class definition or some defined Typescript `type`.  The VSCode error is:

```
 [ts] Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{}' has no index signature
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not guarantee that the symbol-named property you are using has been declared on `T`.  You can constrain `T` to be a type that declares the property:

```
const symbolId = Symbol('id');
function attachUUID<T extends { [symbolId]: string }>(o: T) {
   o[symbolId]=v1();
}
```

Or else cast to `any`:

```
function attachUUID<T>(o: T) {
   (<any>o)[symbolId]=v1();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

... or if you want to assign the symbol to any object:

```
 const idSym = Symbol('id');

 function attachUUID<T>(o:T) {
    type withUUID = T & { [idSym]: string };
    (o as withUUID)[idSym] = v1();
    return o as withUUID;
 }
```

that way you can get typesafety afterwards:

```
 const el = attachUUID({ a: 1 });
 console.log(el.a, el[idSym]);
```

Comment: That's pretty sweet - just curious should the `el[id]` be `el[idSym]` in the console logging statement?